# API for transliterating Hindi (Devanagari script) to Latin script (no English translation)

Tags: javascript, api, transliteration

Is there any transliteration API which I can use in Javascript to convert a Hindi text in Devanagari script to Latin alphabet without translating it.

For example, "नमस्ते", in Hindi, should be converted to "namaste", in English, and not "Hello" (i.e, without translation).

Comment: Your *englisch text* is called *Latin script*.

Comment: Ok. So can devanagri script be converted to latin script using javascript?

Comment: You surely can, but I’ve no idea how. [There are some rules to do this, right?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration) So you’ll need to implement them.

Comment: But making the transliteration engine from scratch will require more time than I have at the moment. Is there no available API, which I may use?

Comment: I don’t know of any, but I’m certainly not an expert on this topic. You just need to iterate through the Devangari string and append the Latin characters to a new string, don’t you? That doesn’t sound that difficult.

Comment: Yes a basic implementation is not that difficult. But as the string becomes more complex, certain combinations of characters should also be accounted for, and then it becomes difficult

Comment: [Here's one.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/transliteration)

Comment: @this-vidor this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The google translate API provides the type of translation which you expect by default.

Check below screenshot.

[image]